# Alternative matrices notation

Tags: matrices, functions, definition

An example of identity function for matrices could be written such as:

\begin{alignat*}{2}
    f:\mathcal{M}_{m,n}(\mathbb{R}) & \to \mathcal{M}_{m,n}(\mathbb{R}) \\
    x_{ij} & \to x_{ij} \\
  \end{alignat*}

I am working on a project where I need to build such definitions with the requirement to reflect existing code, such as:

```
for m in range(M):
    for n in range(N):
        y[m,n] = x[m,n]
```

To achieve the task, I thought about:

\begin{alignat*}{2}
f:\mathcal{M}_{M,N}(\mathbb{R}) & \to \mathcal{M}_{M,N}(\mathbb{R}) \\
x_{mn} & \to x_{mn} \\
  \end{alignat*}

Is this irreparably against some rules I am not aware about?

If so, is there any better alternative?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: The indices are just variables.  From a mathematical standpoint, it doesn't matter what you call them.  That being said, I think that this is really more of a coding question than a mathematics question, and "is this acceptable?" really seems like you are looking for people's opinions on this, rather than an authoritative, objective answer.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I am just not a maths guy, so I have no culture of what can be or can not be done. If you tell me what I thought about is fine, then I go ahead. If you tell me it is not for a reason I ignore, then I take note. No more no less. I edited my post, btw.

Comment: There is no problem, assuming that your programming language is case sensitive. There is a quote somewhere on this site roughly along the lines of: “a sign of mathematical maturity is accepting that truth is invariant with notation”. So long as your mapping is an identity mapping, variable naming is simply up to your programming style and conventions, and is not mandated to be any one particular way

Comment: @FShrike thanks for the answer and for the quote, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: @Synthase Notational conventions are important if you’re trying to communicate ideas with people, write papers or even be able to read other papers and articles however - if you don’t know the standards, it’s very easy to get lost when reading someone else’s work. Same applies for programming if you’re working with a team... but the mathematics itself simply doesn’t matter. I’d absolutely advocate for using $i,j$ instead, as it’s more idiomatic for both maths and programming to use as indices, but it doesn’t really matter!

Comment: @FShrike It is actually about writing an academic paper presenting an educational library. The idea is to put side-by-side code, math and graphical representation. But then everything need to be homogeneous, which is difficult. And it must be driven by the code, so I need to align the maths to it :).